keep getting this error on a fresh ubuntu 24 lts, although my rustc version is 1.78.0
error: package solana-program v1.18.14 cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.75.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.68.0-dev
Either upgrade to rustc 1.75.0 or newer, or use
cargo update -p solana-program@1.18.14 --precise ver
where ver is the latest version of solana-program supporting rustc 1.68.0-dev

Does this answer your question? How do I fix "package solana-program v1.18.0 cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.72.0 or newer"?

hi bro Is Solana 24 LTS suitable for Solana and rust or not?

It's probably a mismatch between the Solana version you are using, which defaults to the latest version in your Cargo.toml
Update to the latest version
solana-install init 1.18.14


me it's worse than this because i either get this error
and when i upgrade to solana 1.18.0 i get a stack offset error when anchor build.

the stack offset error can be solved by switching to solana-program 0.18.2

If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - From Review
